# My app crash on startup and launch normally when resume

Tags: ios, crash

My app crash's on start up while being on splash screen. After it crash's then double click home button and I found out that it is in "app gallery", just like as if it went to the background. Click the app, splash window would come again and this time, it launch's normally. This very strange.

I've got the crash log, but I lost the dSYM file for some reason, so I can't exactly locate the bug. The crash log is just like this:

(yes, only one thread in crash log; there should be many in fact.)

> ```
> 0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182538f60 <redacted> + 148
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000197087f80 objc_exception_throw + 56
> 2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182538e90 <redacted> + 0
> 3   stockmap-ios                        0x00000001005d6fc4 stockmap-ios + 5156804
> 4   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x0000000197ab593c _sigtramp + 52
> 5   stockmap-ios                        0x00000001003fa7ec stockmap-ios + 3205100
> ```

Another thing make me upset is that, I can only reproduce this crash on production mode (after build to .ipa), but I'm not able to do this on development mode. That makes me crazy... As you know I lack dSYM so the crash log is to some extent useless.

My query are:-

1. What are the differences between this two modes?
2. What could be the possible solution?

---

environment info:

- iOS: 9
- device: On Ipad2, Iphone6 and Iphone6s.(Unknown about others)

Comment: Did you do smth on splash screen view? You should debug it from `AppDelegage` file to know how did it make crash

Comment: @CongTran 

Thank you for your advice.

* what do you mean "smth"?
* I'm using titanium platform, which enable us write code in javascript. And those native interfaces are meant to be managed by titanium. If so, I have to dive into their sdk and debug. That's a heavy work, and is my last choice.

Comment: hum, sorry man, I'm not framilier with titanium and have no idea to help :(

Comment: Are you using Swift or Obj-C?

Comment: @LoVo titanium uses Obj-C

Comment: This question seems to be posted twice, with the first instance being: [My app crash on startup and luanch normally when resume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34511036/my-app-crash-on-startup-and-luanch-normally-when-resume)