# My app crash on startup and luanch normally when resume

Tags: ios, crash

My app crash on start up, on splash screen. After it crashes, double click home button, and I find that it is in "app gallery", just like as if it went to the background. Click it, splash window came again and this time, it launch normally. This very strange.

I've got the crash log, but I lost the dSYM file for some reason, so I can't exactly locate the bug. The crash log is just like this:

(yes, only one thread in crash log; there should be many in fact.)

> ```
> 0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182538f60 <redacted> + 148
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000197087f80 objc_exception_throw + 56
> 2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182538e90 <redacted> + 0
> 3   stockmap-ios                        0x00000001005d6fc4 stockmap-ios + 5156804
> 4   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x0000000197ab593c _sigtramp + 52
> 5   stockmap-ios                        0x00000001003fa7ec stockmap-ios + 3205100
> ```

Another thing make me upset is that, I can only reproduce this crash on production mode (after build to .ipa), but I'm not able to do this on development mode. That makes me crazy... As you know I lack dSYM so the crash log is to some extent useless.

For my code, What are the differences between this two modes?

---

env info:

- os: ios 9
- device: at least, happens on Ipad2, Iphone6, Iphone6s. unknow about others.

Comment: You'll get better answers if you post this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Are you making some http requests ? (not https)

Comment: @RedEagle2000 thank you, I will do.

Comment: @MrMojoRisin 
I does not exactly know as I use titanium. there is http reqs in app but may not be at launch time. why do you ask this?

Comment: I have got a crash problem before because of Apple restrictions for secure connexions. And it was working perfectly on development mode.

Comment: @MrMojoRisin
As I know, titanium did this:

Comment: @MrMojoRisin

>     App Transport Security Settings:
>         Allow Arbitrary Loads: **YES**